# How to get all the current year holidays from google calendar API using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

Following code get events from calendar API but i want to get current year Holidays please help me..

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
   process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-api-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
   if (err) {
      console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
      return;
   }
   // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
   // Google Calendar API.
   console.log("content " + content);
   authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
   var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
   var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
   var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
   var auth = new googleAuth();
   var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

   // Check if we have previously stored a token.
   fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
      if (err) {
         getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
      } else {
         oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
         callback(oauth2Client);
      }
   });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
   var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES
   });
   console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
   var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
   });
   rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
      rl.close();
      oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
         if (err) {
            console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            return;
         }
         oauth2Client.credentials = token;
         storeToken(token);
         callback(oauth2Client);
      });
   });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
   try {
      fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
   } catch (err) {
      if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
         throw err;
      }
   }
   fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
   console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
   var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
   calendar.events.list({
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime'
   }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
         console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
         return;
      }
      var events = response.items;
      if (events.length == 0) {
         console.log('No upcoming events found.');
      } else {
         console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var event = events[i];
            var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
            console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
         }
      }
   });
}
```

I want to get whole the current year holiday from Google calendar API.please give me solution if any one knows.

Answer (score 0):

There are public calendars for national holidays you just have find the calendar id for the one you want.

The best way to do this is to go into your Google Calendar on the left hand side at the bottom it says other calendars, click on the drop down menu pick `browse interesting calendars`, there is a large list.

Add the calendar to your Google calendar click on the arrow next to it and check Calendar settings.  It will tell you the ID for the calendar en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com, en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com

There are even ones for Christian holidays , Jewish holidays, orthodox holidays.

You can then use that calendar id in your code.

Comment: ok, i got calendar ID but i have work with google calendar API at first time. that's why i don't understand exactly code functionality and how to use tat calendar ID.

Comment: at which place should i use that ID?

Comment: calendarId: 'primary',  <--- looks like the logical place to me and I have never used node.js :)

Comment: i found error: 'The API returned an error: Error: Not Found'.

Comment: I just tested it here it does work https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list  if you are getting not found then your calendar id is incorrect which calendar are you looking for?

Comment: i want holidays in india and my calendar Id is  'en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'

Comment: Just tested it that's the correct ID I cant tell you why your code isn't working.